# Mkbootimg: Repacking Android recovery produce corrupted image

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, google, partitions, data-corruption

I want to replace the kernel inside twrp 12.1 recovery with my kernel that I built.

Now with only unpacking and repacking the recovery image I end up with an image of different size

The recovery image size is 128M

```
root@localhost:~/mkbootimg# ls -alth recovery.img

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 128M Jul 15 12:40 recovery.img
```

The tool I'm using is [google mkbootimg](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/mkbootimg/)

mkbootimg -h

```
usage: unpack_bootimg.py [-h] --boot_img BOOT_IMG [--out OUT] [--format {info,mkbootimg}] [-0]

Unpacks boot, recovery or vendor_boot image.

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --boot_img BOOT_IMG   path to the boot, recovery or vendor_boot image
  --out OUT             output directory of the unpacked images
  --format {info,mkbootimg}
                        text output format (default: info)
  -0, --null            output null-terminated argument strings

Output format:

  * info

    Pretty-printed info-rich text format suitable for human inspection.

  * mkbootimg

    Output shell-escaped (quoted) argument strings that can be used to
    reconstruct the boot image. For example:

    $ unpack_bootimg --boot_img vendor_boot.img --out out --format=mkbootimg |
        tee mkbootimg_args
    $ sh -c "mkbootimg $(cat mkbootimg_args) --vendor_boot repacked.img"

    vendor_boot.img and repacked.img would be equivalent.

    If the -0 option is specified, output unescaped null-terminated argument
    strings that are suitable to be parsed by a shell script (xargs -0 format):

    $ unpack_bootimg --boot_img vendor_boot.img --out out --format=mkbootimg \
        -0 | tee mkbootimg_args
    $ declare -a MKBOOTIMG_ARGS=()
    $ while IFS= read -r -d '' ARG; do
        MKBOOTIMG_ARGS+=("${ARG}")
      done <mkbootimg_args
    $ mkbootimg "${MKBOOTIMG_ARGS[@]}" --vendor_boot repacked.img
```

Running the commands the tools suggests

```
root@localhost:~/mkbootimg# ./unpack_bootimg.py --boot_img recovery.img  --out out --format=mkbootimg |     tee mkbootimg_args
--header_version 2 --os_version 16.1.0 --os_patch_level 2127-12 --kernel out/kernel --ramdisk out/ramdisk --recovery_dtbo out/recovery_dtbo --dtb out/dtb --pagesize 0x00001000 --base 0x00000000 --kernel_offset 0x00008000 --ramdisk_offset 0x01000000 --second_offset 0x00000000 --tags_offset 0x00000100 --dtb_offset 0x0000000001f00000 --board '' --cmdline 'console=ttyMSM0,115200n8 earlycon=msm_geni_serial,0xa90000 androidboot.hardware=qcom androidboot.console=ttyMSM0 androidboot.memcg=1 lpm_levels.sleep_disabled=1 video=vfb:640x400,bpp=32,memsize=3072000 msm_rtb.filter=0x237 service_locator.enable=1 androidboot.usbcontroller=a600000.dwc3 swiotlb=2048 cgroup.memory=nokmem,nosocket reboot=panic_warm buildvariant=eng'
root@localhost:~/mkbootimg# nano mkbootimg_args
root@localhost:~/mkbootimg# sh -c "./mkbootimg.py  $(cat mkbootimg_args) -o  repacked.img"                root@localhost:~/mkbootimg# ls -alth repacked.img
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 67M Jul 15 22:20 repacked.img
root@localhost:~/mkbootimg#
```

I had to modify mkbootimg_args and change `--header_version` to 3 because the tool didn't like it
but you can see the `repacked.img` is 67M where the original `recovery.img` is 128M
Flashing the repacked image to recovery partition I end up with destroyed boot/recovery screen